# How to make Isabelle use ZF?

Tags: isabelle

What's the trick to making Isabelle find `src/ZF/Main.thy` instead of `src/HOL/Main.thy`?

None of the ZF examples work if I just load them into the IDE, but it looks like that's because it doesn't know to use the ZF axioms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I generally start Isabelle with `isabelle jedit`, and usually with a parameter `-l` specifying the logic, e.g.

```
isabelle jedit -l HOLCF
```

or, in your case, presumably

```
isabelle jedit -l ZF
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems the relevant setting is supplied by the dropdown in the Theories tab, or under Plugins → Isabelle → General → Logic.

The trick is to select `Logics_ZF`, *and then restart Isabelle/jEdit*.

Comment: `Logics_ZF` happens to work, but it is actually a manual about `ZF` based on it.  It is sufficient to switch to `ZF` as session for Isabelle/jEdit.